# KIVY : Scroll Bar missing

Tags: kivy, scrollview

I am trying my hands on ScrollView within anchorlayout. Unable to get scroll bar in Relativelayout. Please find below my sample code. Why scrollbar is not visible.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollView>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    DrawingSpace:
        size_hint: 1,1
''')

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root=DrawingSpace()
        return self.root

class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget( Button(text = 'Scroll', size_hint=(None,None), size=(50,200), pos = (100, 100)))
        self.add_widget( Button(text = 'Scroll', size_hint=(None,None), size=(50,200), pos = (250, 300)))

Factory.register('DrawingSpace', cls=DrawingSpace)

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    Window.size = (200, 200)
    app = Main()
    app.run()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ScrollView`, in the direction you want scrolling, you have to set `size_hint` to `None` and specify the size. I used 500 for testing.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollView>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    DrawingSpace:
        size_hint: 1,None
        height: 500
''')

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root=ScrollView()
        return self.root

class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget( Button(text = 'Scroll', size_hint=(None,None), size=(50,200), pos = (100, 100)))
        self.add_widget( Button(text = 'Scroll', size_hint=(None,None), size=(50,200), pos = (250, 300)))

Factory.register('DrawingSpace', cls=DrawingSpace)

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    Window.size = (200, 200)
    app = Main()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution works. But can this changes be made in KV instead of python code please.

Comment: You're right. It turns out only 3 little changes in your code were needed to make scroll work. I've updated my answer.